# where is cygwin's wget

Tags: cygwin, wget

Did `wget` move to a package? I use to use `setup.exe` and search for `wget` to install it. I don't see it anymore.

The net package is already installed. Both attempts to run `wget` and `locate wget` turn up nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` is in its own package and is still available through `setup.exe`. You might try a different download site.

Comment: it was pointed to a local download of files.  I had them re-direct setup.exe to go to the Internet instead...